# How to send email from Contact Form in Drupal 7?

Tags: email, drupal-7, xampp, contact-form

Currently, I am developing a website using Drupal 7 in my local computer.
I have set up Contact Form (Drupal core module) for user to send feedbacks.
However, I have no idea how to send email from Contact form. I didn't receive any email after I filled in and submitted the contact form. And website displays the status "The message has been sent." But there is no email received.

I know there must be something I need to setup before using Contact Form. Maybe mail server?

I use Drupal 7 with XAMPP.

Is there any step-by-step guideline on sending email? Maybe for both cases

1. Local machine as web server (for testing on my local computer)
2. Real web server (for publishing after everything is done)

I have searched some solutions in some forums but I do not understand.
I am new to Drupal.
Thank you so much for your help and guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For getting mail from contact form,

1. Enable the module
2. Go to admin-> structure-> contact form
3. Create new category
4. Fill the details Category, **Recipients** (you need to give the mail you need to get  notified), etc...

If you need to test the mail in local then you need to setup [SMTP](https://www.drupal.org/project/smtp) module in your drupal, this will work in server also.

If you don't have any any SMTP settings then you need to test in server. In server you may don't need any smtp mail, simply php mail may work if your hosting server is support. So no need to do any extra effort for that.

Comment: I use SMTP module that you suggested. And it works in my local computer! Thanks a lot! I will try in web server.

Comment: I have tried in web server, SMTP doesn't work! T_T Is there anything I have to change? Thanks again! :D

Comment: In server, just as you mentioned, it works without SMTP! Thanks so much! :)